# Compare two cdroms

Tags: linux, data-cd, hashsum

I would like to verified if two CD-ROMs (UDF) identical or not.

One cdrom will be read at Windows and the other CD-ROM at Linux, where the CD-ROMs can be with different burning programs. This means that they can be padded with different amount of zeros at the end of the CD-ROMs.

Until know, with ISO files, i used isosize and then with the help of dd and md5sum, a md5sum generated and compared between the two systems. This approach is not possible with UDF CD-ROMs, since isosize is only for ISO CD-ROMs.

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom bs=2048 count=`isosize -d 2048 /dev/cdrom`| md5sum
```

Any idea how to compute a md5sum of the CD-ROM without the padded zeros?

Comment: If you have two ISO files, you can use `cmp` instead of `md5sum`. Not only will `cmp` tell you if the files differ, but also at which byte. So you can look at the difference in detail and decide whether it's padding or not.

Comment: @frostschutz, thank you for your answer. I have two cases, one is the CD-ROM with ISO file system and the other is with UDF file system.